# Action bar tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments

im trying to use action bar tabs and i have some questions.

1. I see from the developers blog that i need to use Fragment layout. I have in my wanted layout buttons that the margins between them is depends on the screen size.
   I used to do in Relative layout but in Fragment layout it doest work.
   Is there a way to change the view position from the java code?
2. My views dont respone to setOnClickListener anymore.
   I tried using this code:

   View homePageLayout = View.inflate(this, R.layout.home_page, null);

   workoutWall = (ImageButton) homePageLayout.findViewById(R.id.workoutWall);

   workoutWall.setOnClickListener(this);

And my fragemnts code:

```
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(tab.getPosition() == 0)
        {
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_place, fragmentHome, null);
            setTheMarging();
        }
        else
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_place, fragmentExtra, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
      public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Restore the previously serialized current tab position.
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
          getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
        }
      }

     @Override
      public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // Serialize the current tab position.
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActionBar()
            .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
      }

     public static class HomePageFragment extends Fragment
     {
            public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "placeholder_text";

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_page, container, false);
            }
     }

     public static class ExtrasFragment extends Fragment
     {
            public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "placeholder_text";

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.extras, container, false);
            }
     }

Thanks for helping
```

Comment: You don't need to use a fragment layout... Look at abs example projects.